# Support Vector Machine on Highly Sparse Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, svm, sparse-matrix

I am currently with problem of using **SVM on highly sparse dataset** . The problem is I have N*M dataset where N-number of example and M- number of features . **Each N has hardly 10 features present** .

As of now I am representing the features as binary vectors ie 1 if the feature is present in given 0 if now . **The dataset is balance and I am getting accuracy of 94% .Also ROC is 0.93** .  I am trying to understand why this accuracy is coming high .

**(1)Could anyone please guide me to related paper where sparse dataset is giving high accuracy where I can try to find the reason of such high accuracy .**

**(2) Also I am planning to use SciKit Learn . Could anyone suggest me which function I should use in scikit learn in SVM which is designed for such high sparsicity dataset .**

**(3)Also if any one can try to explain me the reason behind such high accuracy , then it would be great .**

**(4) Also if I change binary feature representation to some weighted representation , will it give me some advantage .**

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, sparse training data does not neccessarily mean that the classification accuracy must be low. If you can find a good decision boundary, it doesn't matter if the data is sparse. Remember that support vectors themselves are a very small (= sparse) subset of the data, but they are still sufficient for classification purposes. As always the case with machine learning, algorithm results highly depend on the problem domain and parameters chosen.

For your 2nd question, the first google result for "svm sparse data" reveals this link:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html

As for the 4th question, you will only know the answer once you've tried it out, no one can predict the result without knowing more details about your approach and the data in question.